# Chamar automaticamente os bower_components no header

Tags: grunt, bower

Estou usando bower para baixar e manter as dependencias que vou precisar usar no projeto.
Se entendi correto posso rodar um bower update e vai atualiza-las pra mim.

Estou com jquery, bootstrap, backbone na pasta bower_components mas não esta sendo chamado no meu "header.php", como fazer isso automaticamente? Para sempre atualizar com as novas versões que serão baixadas no futuro?

Devo usar Grunt pra isso? Ele vai chamar as dependencias em algum arquivo que eu selecionar?

Comment: Qual o problema em inserir manualmente um caminho `/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js`? Nesse caso, se você atualizar o `jQuery` com o `bower`, o browser ja vai baixar a versão atualizada.

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei essa solução, um plugin pra Grunt que injeta diretamente no html: https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-wiredep

Comment: Alem do wiredep você pode utilizar o grunt-usemin para automatizar a minificação destes arquivos.